# Tubus rack compatibility

Tags: compatibility, touring-bikes

I have [author ronin 2019](http://en.author.eu/adventure/gravel-bike/author-ronin-2019-ua42913002-6404) and I'm wondering if [this tubus rack](https://www.bike-components.de/en/tubus/Tara-Lowrider-Front-Rack-p47758/) suits to the fork of my bike. Did anybody use this front racks with similar forks?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Ronin in particular, but I have the Tubus Tara on my Salsa Fargo, which has a very similar front fork setup, and it works fine. I had to use all of the provided spacers to get the rack to clear the calipers, but that's it.

It can be a little tight and finicky getting everything lined up when mounting the rack and taking it back off, but it's not a big deal if you're not doing that very often.